# PowerBuilder 12.5.1 and Windows 8 incompatibilities?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, windows-8.1, powerbuilder

I have a PowerBuilder 12.5.1 application developed on Windows 7 64-bit.
I would like to have it running on Windows 8.1 64-bit, connecting to Microsoft SQL Server 2008r2.
The application starts, display initial window with lots of textboxes/checkboxes/etc and can even access the database from PowerScript and read the output of a query into a variable.
But when the application tries to open a window containing a datawindow, then it crashes.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Give some more details. What kind of crash? What is the faulty module? `pbvm125.dll`? Does it crash when running from the IDE, or with the deployed version? Does it crash even with a very simple dw with a simple query like `select 42`?

Comment: It crashes with "the application XXXX.exe has terminated", no idea which module. It crashes even when opening a window containing a datawindow object, but no datawindow inside it.

Comment: Workaround found:

1) Use "PowerBuilder Runtime Packager" on Windows 8.1
2) Run the newly created runtime package on the target Windows 8.1 machine, there will be an error on pbjvm125, ignore it

Then I can run my PowerBuilder application (compiled on Windows 7) on the target Windows 8.1 machine

Comment: One more clarification: the crash is in the compiled executable.

Comment: You are developing on Win7. How do you deploy on the Win8 host? Maybe that you are missing some of the PB runtime dlls. Do you have the `pbdwe125.dll` along with `pbvm125.dll`? BTW, when you get the "app has crashed" message box don't you have a "details" button to get some technical details on the crash? You can also look in the event viewer (windows administrative tools) / Windows / application to have some details on the app crash.

Comment: Using the Runtime packager should have deployed the needed libraries (which I though they were missing) to your win8 host.